# Prevent Autofitting when pasting values into a cell

Tags: excel, vba

Hello fellow VBA enthusiasts,

I have a 2D array of data, I want to paste into a range. Two values in each row might be a wall of text. When I paste this array into a range, excel resizes the rows to fit that wall of text.

Is there a way to prevent this Autofitting when pasting?

My solution so far is to resize all the rows after the fact. Would be nice to not be needing to do so. And I could find anything on the web, all the questions were exactly the opposite of what i need.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why exactly it adds a True value to `.WrapText` to the cell with the bigger text but you can turn it off easily after pasting your array like so:

```
Sub Macro4()
    Dim arr
    arr = Range("A1:A3").Value
    With Range("B5").Resize(UBound(arr, 1))
        .Value = arr
        .WrapText = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to help a fellow vba enthusiast :)